# how to prevent break letters using paragrph witn anime js

Tags: javascript, letter, anime.js

how to prevent break letters using paragraph witn anime.js

```
var textWrapper = document.querySelector('.ml13');

textWrapper.innerHTML = textWrapper.textContent.replace(/\S/g, "<span class='letter'>$&</span>");

anime({
    targets: '.ml13 .letter',
    translateY:15,
    opacity: [0,1],
    easing: "easeOutExpo",
    duration: 2600,
    delay: (el, i) => 100 + 20 * i
  

  });
```

Comment: I don't understand the question, what it should do?

Comment: I would like to avoid breaking words
this example works only for headilines but not with paragraphs